# GEC and NM cable through same hole?

Tags: electrical, wiring, grounding, studs, 240v

I'm replacing old 240v wiring in our home and the grounding electrode conductor was put through the same hole in the stud as the 240v cable was. I am not wanting to drill any more holes in the studs than necessary so I want to know if this is acceptable or not. I will have my work inspected and just want to avoid having to redo my work. Is it permissible to pass the GEC through the same hole as my new 240v NM cable?

Thank you,
Ben[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run the GEC through the same hole as other cables.

The GEC is a non-current-carrying conductor, so there is no heating issues to worry about.